# Hatch in polygon with small gaps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

In the green polygon of the area below there are some small gaps between the hatches. It is interesting that these gaps appear in the pdf exported from the ArcGIS (we used 450 dpi) and in the layout view as well if you use a similar scale as the one showed in the image.

If you zoom in, these gaps between the hatches disappear.

Does someone know a solution for this?

I took a photo of the printed version of the map:

[image: I took a photo of the printed version of the map.]